# Twitch API not returning anything

Tags: javascript, api, axios, next.js, twitch

I want to use the Twitch API to request the current top streams as documented here 'https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-streams' The code below is currently what I have, Am I passing the bearer token wrong? and is their another way? When the page renders it's stuck on the 'Loading...' div, seemingly like it isn't even calling the API.

[image]

```
import axios from "axios";
import { chakra, Box, Image, Flex, Icon, useColorModeValue, HStack, Grid, Wrap, WrapItem } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { MdHeadset, MdEmail, MdLocationOn } from "react-icons/md";
import { BsFillBriefcaseFill } from "react-icons/bs";

const Streams = ({streams}) => {
    if(!streams){
       return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
    console.log(streams);
    return (
        <div>
          <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

Streams.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get("https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams", { 
        headers: {
          'Authorization' : 'Bearer abcdef',
          'Client-ID' : 'abcdef',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : true,
        }
      });
      const streams = res.data;
      console.log(streams)
      return { streams };
    } catch (error) {
      return { error };
    }
  };
  

  export default Streams;
```

Comment: *"should be working but it's not"* what is not working? What errors do you get?

Comment: Just saying "It's not working" [is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: Currently nothing I might need to change the title I sought of rushed this. But the page isn't returning anything it's just stuck on the Loading... div? It's like it's not even getting to call the api

Comment: So how does the postman request look like? And can you check in the browser dev tools if the request is done and what is the result?

Comment: I've added the postman results, console log shows nothing and the network tab in dev tools shows nothing from Twitch

Comment: @MatDoak `getInitialProps` runs on the server on initial page load, look for any logs on the terminal where you started the dev server. Is it returning the expect output?